# Creating d3.selection.enter.prototype in v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some existing d3 code that stopped working once I upgraded to the latest D3 version 4.  Looks like I can no longer extend selections using this approach...

```
d3.selection.enter.prototype.mything = function()
{
    var linkEnter = this.append("line").... etc
    return linkEnter;
}
```

That syntax now gives me error...

- TypeError: d3.selection.enter is undefined

Does anyone know how to extend selections in v4 of D3?

Comment: `d3.selection.prototype.enter.prototype`?

Comment: Struggling with the same issue.